# Use a syntax list as formal parameters to a function

Tags: macros, racket

This is the scenario: Given a pattern of the form `[sym ...]` (e.g. `[a b]` and `[a b c d]`) I want to generate (using macros) functions that concatenate the symbols in the pattern, but also supply them as arguments. For example, `[a b]` transforms to something of the form

```
(define (ab a b) 
  body)
```

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776548/racket-macro-to-define-functions-given-a-repeated-pattern) someone helps me generate the name of the function via a syntax class called `signal-list`. In the following code I can match the `signals` pattern variable with a pattern of the form `(sig ...)`, and I can then use it to generate the desired function definition.

```
(define-syntax (define-something stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ (signals:signal-list body ...))
     (syntax-parse #'signals
       [(sig ...)
        #'(define (signals.concatenated-ids sig ...)
               body ...)])]))
```

An example that matches this macro:

```
(define-something
  ([a b] 'body))
```

which expands to `(define (ab a b) 'body)`

But how do macros work if I want to generate multiple function definitions? For example:

```
(define-something
  ([a b] 'body)
  ([c d e] 'body))
=>
(begin (define (ab a b) 'body)
       (define (cde c d e) 'body))
```

I can add an ellipsis in the pattern of the first syntax-parse:

`(_ (signals:signal-list body ...) ...)`

But then I cannot use the second syntax-parse to match against `signals` because it needs an ellipsis. Is there a different way to 'de-construct' `signals` so that I can use its contents as formal parameters to a function, which is compatible with using ellipses?

Comment: The [answer you mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34777089/343414) already defines multiple functions, so, I'm not sure what you're asking here?  Note that that answer works because it uses the same number of ellipses in both the pattern and template.

Comment: It does, and I understand why it does it, but with the additional requirement of supplying the combined ids as formal parameters I got quite confused. I should really do more research on syntax classes to properly understand what is going on. I am convinced the answer is quite trivial. The Racket docs on macros are not so friendly to people who don't crunch macros for breakfast.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to define new pattern variables. `syntax-parse` is one (rather heavyweight) way to do it. As Chris suggested, `with-syntax` is an easier way to define local pattern variables. The idiomatic way to define local pattern variabes with `syntax-parse` is with the `#:with` [pattern directive](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-specifying.html?q=%23%3Awith#%28tech._pattern._directive%29), eg `#:with ((sig ...) ...) #'signals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you can pass `#'(signals ...)` (in place of your existing `#'signals`) to the inner `syntax-parse` invocation.

---

As a proof of concept, I wrote a `syntax-case` version of your macro (since I don't know `syntax-parse` yet). You should be able to adapt the same technique to `syntax-parse` easily:

```lisp
(define-syntax (define-something outerstx)
  (define (make-name paramstx)
    (datum->syntax outerstx
                   (string->symbol
                    (apply string-append
                           (map symbol->string (syntax->datum paramstx))))))

  (define (make-names innerstx)
    (syntax-case innerstx ()
      (()
       #'())
      (((param ...) rest ...)
       (with-syntax ((name (make-name #'(param ...)))
                     ((next ...) (make-names #'(rest ...))))
         #'(name next ...)))))

  (syntax-case outerstx ()
    ((_ ((param ...) body ...)
        ...)
     (with-syntax (((name ...) (make-names #'((param ...) ...))))
       #'(define-values (name ...)
           (values (lambda (param ...)
                     body ...)
                   ...))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it guided me to the solution. In case other people stumble on this question: Rather than using the inner syntax-parse, I used `with-syntax` to match a pattern `((sig ...) ...)` against the `#'(signals ...)` syntax. The body of the first syntax-parse looks something like this: `(with-syntax ([((sig ...) ...)  #'(signals ...)])   #'())`. The key insight I was missing is that it is indeed perfectly possible to "de-construct" things -- via _pattern matching_. This should have been obvious to me, but it was not. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the literals list and `syntax-parse` is drop-in replacement for `syntax-case` :)